string to int not giving desired output
print("int==1.0--\(Int("1.0") ?? 0)")
print("int==1--\(Int("1") ?? 0)")

Output I am getting
int==1.0--0
int==1--1

Output I am expecting
int==1.0--1
int==1--1

Any idea why first line is not giving output as 1
Note :
print("int==1--\(Int(1.0) )")

This give output as 1.

This question is similar to: What is the ?? operator?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.    ("first trying to get value from Int("1.0"). If that has nil then it will try assign value 0.")

@Luuk : Why its duplicated? for sure I didn't ask for ?? and I know what ?? does...

The reason is that "1.0" is not a valid string representation of an integer so Int("1.0") doesn't return integer value that's why you got 0 instead of 1.
I provide updated code.
if let floatVal = Double("1.0") {
    print("int==1.0--\(Int(floatVal))")
} else {
    print("int==1.0--0")
}
print("int==1--\(Int("1") ?? 0)")

I hope it helps you.

The init you are calling when using a string argument is documented here and has the following requirement for the input
The string passed as description may begin with a plus or minus sign character (+ or -), followed by one or more numeric digits (0-9).
Since your string also contains a period it violates this rule and the init will fail and return nil.
For the other init that takes a Double the documentation states that
Any fractional part of the value passed as source is removed, rounding the value toward zero.
so this will correctly return 1.

Just one line solution:
print("int==1.0--\(Int(Float("1.0") ?? 0.0))")
print("int==1--\(Int("1") ?? 0)")

